SDK update 33 to 34
Android 14 (API level 34) introduces several improvements, including a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security.
The Play Core Library uses broadcast receivers and has already been updated to be compatible with Android 14. You should update to a newer version of the library as soon as possible as older versions of the Play Core library may crash in apps targeting Android 14. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play will require all new app releases to target Android 14.
Your app still uses a version of the Play Core library that is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34, listed here:
To avoid potential crashes, update the Play Core Maven dependency in your app. Some of your affected projects are listed below:
Play Console will also alert you if there are outdated dependencies the next time you upload a project
What do I need to do?
We recommend that you update your Play Core Maven dependency to the latest version as soon as possible to avoid any disruptions in your app.
We’re here to help
We’re here to ensure you have a smooth migration. If you have any issues or questions, please visit the Play Console Help Center.
I tried to update compileSdkVersion 33 , targetSdkVersion 33 to 34 but facing build failure, Need to fix it
